# Shopify liquid code, how to use screensize

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, screen-size

I want to display radio boxes and dropdowns for selecting a variant on desktop and only dropdowns on mobile.

At the moment it displays the desktop variant on both. And I would have to differ within the liquid code which creates the dropdowns/radio boxes between the screen size. So that it can create the right elements.

But as liquid can not differ between it. I need a workaround for it.

I can also not put a  around it and differ with js, because the liquid code in it does not work anymore.

Does someone know a workaround for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem as well, I found some sort of workaround.

I create both needed elements (dropdown and radio boxes) for this one option and just remove one of them depending on the screen size:

```
if (screen.width < 912) {
  var child = document.getElementById("packaging-selection-desktop");
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
else {
  var child = document.getElementById("packaging-selection-mobile");
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lightest and optimized solution would be to use a CSS class with media queries instead of JS. If your stylesheet do not already have this kind of utility classes, you may create one.

So, in your HTML/Liquid code, you might write something like:

```
<div class="checkbox-container hide-tablet">
    Your checkbox code
</div>
```

And in your CSS stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width:912px) {
    display:none;
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hello, yes I thought about that too, but as there will automatically be js behind it when creating the element, it has to be completely removed. Otherwise the variants of a product will not work anymore. (Shopify)